# How do I set the background color or image of a cell in a ListView (or ListActivity) on Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, listactivity

How do I set the background color or image of a cell in a ListView (or ListActivity) on Android?

This is a **very** simple ListView with just a few items in it and no other customization. I don't want to change the text or text color or size or anything like that, I just want to change the color or background image of the cells in the ListView.

What is the simplest way to do this in **code** (not layout XML)?

Here is the code I am using in my ListActivity:

```
listitems.add("1");
listitems.add("2");
listitems.add("3");

this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, 
    listitems
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to newbyca for leading me in the right direction. This is what I was looking for and is actually the best answer as it's the easiest code to implement:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, listitems) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        //v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);  // COLOR
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plaincell); // IMAGE
        return v;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try extending ArrayAdapter with something like:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int p, View v, ViewGroup g){
        v = super.getView(p, v, g);
        v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
        return v;
    }

}
```

That would, for example, make each item view's background solid red.

Comment: Don't think this will work for my code... I added what I currently have in my ListActivity right now in my original question.